# errors executing bash command in shell script variable

Tags: bash, shell, sh

In terminal(bash) the following command produces the correct output (an integer)

```
ls -l | grep '.json' | grep -v 'fit-report.json' | wc -l
```

which correctly returns 13.

Trying the same in a shell script:

```
number_reports= $(ls -l | grep '.json' | grep -v 'fit-report.json' | wc -l)
echo "number of reports is $number_reports"
```

produces runtime errors:

```
line 1: ls -l | grep '.json' | grep -v 'fit-report.json' | wc -l: command not found
number of reports is
```

I've tried it without the `$(..)` bracketing as well as storing the var as a string and executing it in another variable, but I couldn't get that working either.

Comment: What is the very first line of your script file?  Also, note that you should probably just say `ls *.json` instead of `ls -l | grep .json`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove spaces around `=`:

```
number_reports=$(ls -l | grep '.json' | grep -v 'fit-report.json' | wc -l)
```

Though parsing `ls` output is not recommended as your file names can have spaces and newlines.

#### UPDATE:

Better to use this script to get your count:

```
number_reports=0
while read -d ''; do
    ((number_reports++))
done < <(find . -maxdepth 1 -name "*.json" -a ! -name "fit-report.json" -print0)

echo "number_reports=$number_reports"
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you want the number of filenames *F* in current directory that end with `.json` but such that *F*≠`fit-report.json` (even though you didn't exactly express this with your chain of `grep`s and pipes).

A straightforward pure bash way, using (extended) globs and arrays:

```
shopt -s nullglob extglob
filenames=( !(fit-report).json )
printf "number of reports is %d\n" "${#filenames[@]}"
```

(no spaces around the `=` sign).

The use of `shopt -s nullglob` is so that the glob expands to nothing if there are no matches (otherwise it expands to itself verbatim) and `shopt -s extglob` to turn on the extended globs.

Then we build an array `filenames` that contains all the file names that end with `.json`, ignoring the file name `fit-report` (that's the `!(fit-report)` part).

Then we print the number of elements in this array (the number of elements in array `filenames` is `${#filenames[@]}`).

If you really want the number of reports in a variable:

```
number_reports=${#filenames[@]}
```

(with no spaces around the `=` sign).

**Note.** this will not count the “hidden” filenames (e.g., `.hidden.json`), unless you `shopt -s dotglob`.

**Note.** [Do not parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: Thanks gniourf_gniourf, I'd never heard of shopt. Both yours and anubhava's answers were equally excellent but I had to give him the checkmark cause he was first though.